# Has anyone used ADOMD.NET with WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, olap, pivot-table, adomd.net

I am trying to find a good way of accessing a Business Intelligence OLAP Cube from C#.

I don't really care much as to how this is done, but since currently I am trying to implement this with the [codeplex WPF Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf), I would be happy if it was something directly related to the tool, but any suggestions are very welcomed.

My WPF skills are lacking, so the tips & tricks on the site aren't enough for me to get how to bind the DataGrid to an OLAP cube.

I presume I should use ADOMD.NET, but not so sure yet if thats the way to go, and if so, how to go about it, tutorials and informative links are baffling me quite significantly.

Since I keep going round in circles when it comes to finding any example of this having been made, I would appreciate any pointers in this regard.

Tutorials, links, personal tips or experiences welcomed.

Extra info: *this is in order to replace the currently used pivot table in an Excel Spread Sheet.*

thanks,

Ric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing I can find is [this xaml pivot table](http://www.sqljunkies.com/WebLog/mosha/archive/2006/10/08/xaml_pivottable.aspx) by Mosha Pasumanski:

[image]
<sub>(source: [mosha.com](http://www.mosha.com/msolap/images/XAML_PivotTable.png))</sub>

Comment: Thank link now goes to http://www.drdobbs.com/database/ - anychance you have the source code and can upload it to Codeplex or a more relaible file host? TIA - I cannot find it anywhere! I know its been decommissioned

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the code that Mosha's article links to was in the wpf.netfx3.com site which has been taken down.